# How to write a regex to look for strings with fixed length with at least one occurrence of a character

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I've been doing some reading on regular expressions and thought I had everything covered, until recently.

I've had to filter out all strings of length 5 which end with the letter t and contain at least one dot inside. The problem arises when I try to limit the size of the string. It works just fine when I first filter out all strings of size 5 and then additionally do the filtering in accordance with the occurrence of a dot inside, but it's a hassle.

What would be the best way to accomplish this using one regex?

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Comment: Please post your code so we can look at it.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an `and` of 2 constraints it is easier to work one at the time. Example:

```
grep '^....t$' | grep '\.'
```

or

```
perl -nlE '/^....t/ and /\./ and say '
```